# Get address that is pointed to from another address

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-address

For practice I am trying to get the address that a certain memory address is pointing at. I have a ***tool*** which shows what result I have to get. In my case it is:

```
"clientApp.exe"+0x11F9B08 -> 0E4C5F90
```

So I am assuming this basically means: `("The base address of the .exe" + 0x11F9B08)` and that points to the address `0x0E4C5F90`.

I already have the base address of the clientApp.exe. I used `EnumProcessModules` and `GetModuleFileNameEx` for that.

*Small snippet*

```
if ( GetModuleFileNameEx( hProcess, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
{
    if(gameName.compare(szModName))
    {
        dwClientBase = (DWORD)hMods[i]; //base address
        break;
    }
}
```

Then later on i'm trying to get the address that is pointed to. But the following give me a whole other result:

```
DWORD result = (DWORD)(dwClientBase + 0x11F9B08);
```

This gives me: `23042824`. And i'm looking for: `0x0E4C5F90`. I guess i'm close, but not sure what I could try next.

Anyone any idea what I should do in order to get the same result as the ***tool*** is giving me?

Comment: It depends - are you looking for virtual or physical addresses?

Comment: `0x11F9B08` may mean just as well the absolute address in the virtual address space of the process. Have you tried that?

Comment: @RageD I'm not really sure actually, how can i tell? I know that `"clientApp.exe"+0x11F9B08` is always the same. But the address that it points to always changes. So i'd guess it's the virtual address space?

Comment: @ybungalobill I'm not really that familiar with this yet, so i'm not sure if i know what you mean with "Have you tried that yet?". Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `dwClientBase`? If it is a `DWORD` then you should cast to a `BYTE *` and then do your arithmetic, making sure to dereference the pointer to return the value pointed to by that address:

```
DWORD result = *(DWORD *)( (BYTE *)dwClientBase + 0x11F9B08);
```

When adding a number to a pointer the compiler will add a number of bytes equal to the number multiplied by the size of the pointer type. This is why we convert to a `BYTE *` first, so what we add on exactly `0x11F9B08` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You do not dereference the pointer. Try either

```
DWORD result = *(DWORD*)(dwClientBase + 0x11F9B08);
```

or

```
DWORD result = *(DWORD*)(0x11F9B08);
```

The cast to `DWORD*` says the compiler to treat the number as a pointer, then dereferencing `*` it causes read the actual number.